# How to say 'only' when there is only one of something

Tags: grammar

I want to say a sentence of the form:

> This is the **only** shop in this town that sells socks.

i.e. there are no other shops in this town that sell socks.
The best I can do is:

> この町で靴下を売る店だけある。

But I think this means that there is nothing in the town other than a shop that sells socks.

How do I express this use of **only**?

Comment: この町で靴下を売る店だけある doesn't mean "there is nothing in the town other than a shop that sells socks" but "(It) has enough capability as a shop to sell socks in this town". だけ here doesn't mean "only" but 丈, namely, "length" or more like "degree" in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is the only shop in this town that sells socks.

The most literal translation ("this" being the subject, and "only" modifying "shop" adjectivally) would be:

> - これがこの町で靴下を売っている**唯一【ゆいいつ】の**店です。
> - これがこの町で靴下を売っている**ただひとつの**店です。
> - これがこの町で靴下を売っている**たったひとつの**店です。 (emphatic, like "one and only one")

Less commonly, 唯一の/etc can be in this position:

> - これが**唯一の**この町で靴下を売っている店です。

And yes, 「この町には靴下を売る店だけがある。」 means "In this town, there is only a shop that sells socks."

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

> この店はこの街で靴下を売っている唯一の店である。

Comment: Why downvote just to this answer? This sounds much better than この町**で**この店だけが靴下を**売る**

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to say it (using the same format you gave).

To add to mikan's response, you can use 「しか」:

この町で靴下を売っている店はこの店しかない。

It sounds a little much for a casual statement but for the sake of giving an example, you can use the term 「のみ」.

E.g. この町で靴下を売っている店はこの店のみである。

Comment: 「だけ」を使った例も一つお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do a change of position of だけ

> この町で、この店だけが靴下を売る。